# Constructing the adjacency matrix of a square lattice

Tags: graphs-and-networks

How can I write an expression that calculates the adjacency matrix of a regular, 2-dimensional network — a square lattice, of 20 by 20 nodes.

Comment: Please show what you have tried. If you haven't yet, please do search the documentation and read up on the basics of working with graphs in Mathematica.

Answer (score 6):

Use `AdjacencyMatrix@GridGraph[{20,20}]`.

Answer (score 5):

Common example graphs like these are built into the `GraphData` function

```
AdjacencyMatrix@GraphData[{"Grid", {10, 10}}]
```

In fact, `GraphData` can immediately output the adjacency matrix by providing an option

```
GraphData[{"Grid", {10, 10}}, "AdjacencyMatrix"]
```

However, it is probably more efficient to define this as a rule and generate the SparseArray directly by defining a function.